# when using swagger-code-gen-cli jar to generate pojo classes , fields in extended classes are missing

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have used the following command to generate pojo's for my spring boot project

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.0.jar generate -i abc.yaml -l java -o pojoFolder
```

All pojos are getting generated in model folder , but few classes are getting extended from base class and they are not containing any fields. so the fields which are specific to extended(child) class are not getting generated, they are being missed out, anyone can suggest any solution?

Comment: Can you post your YAML file? Also, please try the latest version of Codegen - [2.4.0-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/).

Comment: I am using codegen version 2.3, Can't post yaml file , it is like I have API  abc, in abc I have field of another class,private xyz x; so after using jar , it comes as xyz extends ABC but fields of xyz are not generated

Comment: Ok I will try with 2.4 and check

Comment: Also is there any command which can ask the jar not to use inheritance but create each class as separate component